# WCF IErrorHandler Change the StackTrace

Tags: c#, stack-trace, ierrorhandler

I added IErrorHandler  implementation in my WCF server.
When the debugger hit this method :

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
```

It seems that I am loosing all of the stacktrace.
I want to look into the stacktrace (Quick View) at System.Diagnostics.Stacktrace and Understand which WCF method in was the entry point in the current error/exception handling.

Instead of that, I am getting this stack:

> WebApi.DLL!WebApi.ErrorHandler.ProvideFault(System.Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault) Line 29    C#
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ProvideFault(System.Exception e, System.ServiceModel.Channels.FaultConverter faultConverter, ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlerFaultInfo faultInfo) + 0x8e bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ProvideMessageFaultCore(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x118 bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0xab bytes 
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.ProcessError(System.Exception e) + 0x3c3 bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(bool isOperationContextSet) + 0x21e bytes 
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request, bool cleanThread, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x664 bytes 
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x1e3 bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x4b bytes 
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 bytes
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously) + 0x16b bytes 
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue.AsyncQueueReader.Set(System.Runtime.InputQueue.Item item) + 0x41 bytes 
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue.EnqueueAndDispatch(System.Runtime.InputQueue.Item item, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x3d7 bytes
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue.EnqueueAndDispatch(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x7e bytes 
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor.Enqueue(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x66 bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext context, System.Action callback) + 0x22e bytes 
>       System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll!System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result) + 0x12d bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll!System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest() + 0x24e bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll!System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest() + 0x55 bytes
>       System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll!System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(object state) + 0x53 bytes
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) + 0x71 bytes
>       System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(uint error, uint bytesRead, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) + 0x40 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) + 0x96 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       [Native to Managed Transition]